# Assigning a string to a structure's property

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize the array in the main() .But I am getting an error.
This is how the code looks:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class word
{
public:
    char str[20];
};

int main()
{
    word a;
    word b;
    a.str[]="12345";
    b.str[]="67";
}
```

'a' and 'b' are the 2 objects of the class word.

Comment: Don't say "getting an error". Instead, please include the *exact error text* in your question so we know precisely what the issue is. Different compilers have different complaints.

Comment: You don’t need `char str[]` here. What you need is `string str`. If you insist to use `char str[]`, you need to use `memcpy` or `strcpy` to copy chars into it.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using C strings, then you need to copy it over:

```cpp
int main()
{
    word a;
    word b;

    strncpy(a.str, "12345", sizeof(a.str));
    strncpy(b.str, "67", sizeof(b.str));
}
```

If you want to use C++ more effectively, consider using `std::string`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class word
{
public:
    std::string str; // Embrace the std:: prefix, it's there for a reason
};

int main()
{
    word a;
    word b;

    a.str = "12345";
    b.str = "67";
}
```

Where now assignment is super simple.

> Note: Your original code had a syntax error, as `a.str[] = ...` is not valid C++. The `[]` part means "array of unknown/arbitrary length" which can be used in a function signature, but cannot be used in an assignment. You can do `a.str[n] = 'x'` but that assigns one and only one character.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest "[encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))".
Meaning: keep data members private; expose public methods to access private data members (get and set).
*When possible*, use immutable data (write on construction and never change).

You can play with the code online in [here](https://onlinegdb.com/D06Rwrslg).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class word
{
    const string str;
public:
    word(const string &w) : str(w) {}
    word(const char *w)   : str(w) {}

    const string & get() const { return str; }
};

int main()
{
    word a("12345");
    word b("67");

    cout << "Word a = " << a.get() << endl;
    cout << "Word b = " << b.get() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why would you suggest encapsulation for such a trivial structure?